# Can someone please verify my solutions for this probability question on bayes' theorem?

Tags: probability, bayes-theorem

Assume a COVID test can identify the presence of COVID, given that the person has COVID, with probability $p_d$. Assume the test assigns false positives with probability $p_f$ (a test will be positive but the person does not have COVID). Let $p_{\theta}$ be the prior probability a person has COVID.

**a) Calculate the probability that a test subject has COVID, given a test was positive. Do the same given the test was negative. Calculate the probability the test subject doesn’t have COVID given the test was positive, and then do the same for a negative test.**

*** $P(COVID|+)=\frac{P(+|COVID)P(COVID)}{P(+)}$

Using law of total probability for $P(+)$:

$P(+)=P(+|COVID)P(COVID)+P(+|NOCOVID)P(NOCOVID)$

$=p_dp_{\theta}+p_f(1-p_{\theta})$

$\implies P(COVID|+)=\frac{p_{d}p_{\theta}}{p_dp_{\theta}+p_f(1-p_{\theta})}$

*** $P(COVID|-)= \frac{P(-|COVID)P(COVID)}{P(-)}$

$P(-)=P(-|COVID)P(COVID)+P(-|NOCOVID)P(NOCOVID)$

$= (1-p_d)p_{\theta}+(1-p_f)(1-p_{\theta})$

$\implies P(COVID|-)=\frac{(1-p_d)p_{\theta}}{(1-p_d)p_{\theta}+(1-p_f)(1-p_{\theta})}$

*** $P(NOCOVID|+)= 1-P(COVID|+) = 1 - \frac{p_{d}p_{\theta}}{p_dp_{\theta}+p_f(1-p_{\theta})}$

*** $P(NOCOVID|-) = 1 - P(COVID|-) = 1 - \frac{(1-p_d)p_{\theta}}{(1-p_d)p_{\theta}+(1-p_f)(1-p_{\theta})}$

**b) Assume $p_d=0.8$ and $p_f=0.5$, and assume that the prior probability any person has COVID is 0.1. Given a person has COVID, how many positive tests in a row do they need to take to be 99% confident they have it? 99.9%?**

$1-P(COVID|+)^{n} \geq 0.99$

$\implies 1-\Big[ \frac{(0.8)(0.1)}{(0.8)(0.1)+(0.5)(1-0.1)} \Big]^{n}\geq 0.99$

$\implies 1-(0.15)^n\geq 0.99$

$n\geq 2.4$

Need at least three tests.

For 99.9%, perform the same calculation but with 0.999 instead of 0.99. We get

$1-(0.15)^n \geq 0.999$

$\implies n \geq 3.6$

Need at least 4 tests

Comment: (b) seems to assumes successive tests on the same individual are independent - I am not sure that is realistic

Comment: @Henry is that an issue with the question and the way it was posed or is that an issue with my solution?

Comment: It was a comment on the question. Your $\frac{p_{d}p_{\theta}}{p_dp_{\theta}+p_f(1-p_{\theta})}$ looks correct. Your $1 - \frac{(1-p_d)p_{\theta}}{(1-p_d)p_{\theta}+(1-p_f)(1-p_{\theta})}$ also looks right though perhaps better as $\frac{(1-p_f)(1-p_{\theta})}{(1-p_d)p_{\theta}+(1-p_f)(1-p_{\theta})}$.  Your answer to (b) looks strange to me and I think you may want to look at something like $\dfrac{p_{d}^n p_{\theta}}{p_d^n p_{\theta}+p_f^n (1-p_{\theta})}$ and get higher numbers

Comment: @Henry ah, thanks. So I'm trying to set that greater than or equal to 0.99 but it's not as easy to solve for $n$. I plugged it into wolframalpha and it says that there are no roots

Comment: I suspect it is solvable for $n$, particularly if you use log-odds and log-likelihood-ratios.  Or you can simply evaluate it for $n=1,2,\ldots,20$

Comment: @Henry so I'm just trying to figure out why you're trying to use that formula instead, is mine wrong? are you using that formula because you think that assuming that each successive test on the same person is not independent?

Comment: I think your formulae for (a) are correct, though the second can be written better, and your formula for (b) is wrong  in that you are raising the wrong thing to the power $n$

Comment: @Henry ah, okay. so i was able to solve it and I got $n\geq 9.79$ which basically means we need at least 10 positive tests to be 99% sure we have covid. Does that sound right?

Comment: @Henry and for 99.9% sure I got $n\geq 13.13$ which means we need at least 14 tests

Comment: No - I get higher numbers, so for the first $n\ge \dfrac{\log\left(\dfrac{0.99}{1-0.99}\right)-\log\left(\dfrac{p_t}{1-p_t}\right)}{\log\left(\dfrac{p_d}{p_f}\right)} \approx 14.45$ though I may have made an error

Comment: @Henry oh no oops, I was the one who made an error, I just tried again and I got 14.45 as well. So there need to be at least 15 tests to be 99% sure and for 99.9% sure I got $n\geq 19.37$ which means 20 tests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*From comments:*

Your $\dfrac{p_{d}p_{\theta}}{p_dp_{\theta}+p_f(1-p_{\theta})}$ looks correct.

Your $1 - \dfrac{(1-p_d)p_{\theta}}{(1-p_d)p_{\theta}+(1-p_f)(1-p_{\theta})}$ also looks right though $\dfrac{(1-p_f)(1-p_{\theta})}{(1-p_d)p_{\theta}+(1-p_f)(1-p_{\theta})}$ is perhaps better.

Making the (unrealistic in reality) assumption the successive tests of the same person are independent conditioned on that person's actual status, your answer to (b) looks strange to me  in that you are raising the wrong thing to the power $n$. I think you may want to look at something like $\dfrac{p_{d}^n p_{\theta}}{p_d^n p_{\theta}+p_f^n (1-p_{\theta})}$ and get higher numbers. This leads to something solvable for $n$, particularly if you use log-odds and log-likelihood-ratios. Or you can simply evaluate it for $n=1,2,\cdots,20$.

$\dfrac{p_{d}^n p_{\theta}}{p_d^n p_{\theta}+p_f^n (1-p_{\theta})} \ge k$ is the same as $n  \ge  \dfrac{{\log \frac{k}{1-k}  -\log\frac{p_{\theta}}{1-p_{\theta}}}}{\log\frac{p_f}{p_d}}$ and for example with $k=0.99$ I would get $n \ge 14.45$.